# 'body': KeyError in AWS Lambda function for Telegram Bot

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I followed a guide to set up a Telegram Bot through AWS, so after preparing the function (and the gateway API) to handle a simple bot which answers with the same message i stumbled upon a KeyError on the word 'body'. Here's the code:

```
import json
from botocore.vendored import requests

TELE_TOKEN='700794743:AAFtypDtqP3-dOMC5dSX7DqtwVRGNuKZhH8'
URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}".format(TELE_TOKEN)

def send_message(text, chat_id): 
    final_text = "You said: " + text
    url = URL + "/sendMessage?text={}&chat_id={}".format(final_text, chat_id)
    requests.get(url)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = json.loads(event['body'])
    chat_id = message['message']['chat']['id']
    reply = message['message']['text']
    send_message(reply, chat_id)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200
    }
```

'body': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 13, in lambda_handler
message = json.loads(event['body'])
KeyError: 'body'

I don't know what could possibly be wrong, maybe the 'event' json file doesn't actually have a 'body' parameter? Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that the service invoking the API gateway endpoint is actually posting data to it? Lambda event will only contain `body` key if request includes data.

Comment: Print (event) and you will know the input event structure